# using Javascript how to check file exists.No Jquery and Ajax

Tags: javascript

I want to check file exists or not using Javascript only. I dont want to use Jquery and Ajax, simply Javascript. The file I need to test is located on the server, not client side.

Comment: Server-side JavaScript or client-side JavaScript?

Comment: I lol'd. Shall the file be on the server or client? Server is possible with Ajax, which IS simply javascript. It's not possible to check for files on client side.

Comment: This is impossible to do in client side JS without using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I see is using a PHP (or other server-side language, which has access to your files) to print out a list of the files. Then use jQuery `$.post` or ajax to get these results back. It is easier then you might think, but not what you initially asked for.

The reason I am answering this is ofcourse since the answer to your question is 'No, you cannot do anything on a server with javascript'.

But to give an example of jQuery with ajax and PHP:

```
<?php

  $path = htmlspecialchars($_POST['path']);

  if ($files = array_slice(scandir($path), 2))
    echo implode(',', $files);

?>

<script>
  $.post(
    'get_directory.php', 
    {'path':'file_folder'},

    function(file_list) {
      alert(file_list);
    }
  );
 </script>
```

Would give you a list of files from  file_folder. But didn't test it completely, but as you can see this is not that much work. Hacking your way into a fileserver with javascript purely is a alot harder!

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do it in client side with pure JavaScript , you can use some vb script or ActiveX components embedded to the code to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHTTP` and `XMLHTTPRequest` provide the `ability to check HTTP return codes` (such as 404 !NOT FOUND) and including the full response including headers.

what is your reason why you dont want to use XMLHTTP and XMLHTTPRequest?

Comment: I have used following code to get status of request                var request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
request.open('GET', '/RepairDocument/"+doc+".pdf', false);   request.send(null);  
if (request.status == 200)  
alert(request.responseText);  
else
window.close("/RepairDocument/"+".//Repair_Notification_Number"+".pdf"); 
alert("PDF is not generated for this notification please contact HO");

Now I want to close that page not found window through Javascript. I have used window.close() but it does no close the window. How to close this window?